# Grouping by secondary key and counting occurrences within arrays

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

The desired behavior is to aggregate all comments and mentions of specific fields into a list of comments and mentions into frequency tables.

The desired behavior is as follows:

```
{_id: A, user_id: x, comment: "I grow corn and cotton", crop: ["corn", "cotton"], actions: ['grow']}  
{_id: B, user_id: x, comment: "I eat corn.", crop: ["corn"], actions["eat"}
```

Becomes:

```
{_id: x, comments:["I grow corn and cotton", "I eat corn"],  crop_count: {corn:2, cotton:1}, action_count: {"grow":1, "eat":1} }
```

I currently have

```
col.aggregate([ {"$unwind": '$crops'}, 
    {
        "$group": 
            {'_id': "$user_id", 
            "comments": {"$push" : "$comment"},
            "$group": {
                '_id': "$crops",
                'crop_count': {"$sum":1}}
            "$group": {
                 '_id': "$action",
                 'action_count': {"$sum":1}}
        }
    }    
        ])
```

But this returns a "The field '$group' must be an accumulator object" error. When testing for just the crop use case. I am unsure or how to include the action aspect as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are some aggregation operators that can only be applied in [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation and they are called [`$group accumulators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation-group/)

As you are using `$group`, inside another `$group`, so it doesn't recognize it. And, I don't think that nested groups are possible.

It will be difficult to achieve this with pure or basics aggregation. It will be very lengthy query, but I somehow cracked it. I would suggest you to take your time and understand this query. I have provided a link also where you can execute it stage wise. If you get stuck, let me know.

Here is the query:

```py
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$crop',
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
    }
  },
  {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$actions',
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
    }
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$user_id',
      'action_count_temp': {
        '$addToSet': {
          'comment': '$comment',
          'actions': '$actions'
        }
      },
      'crop_count_temp': {
        '$addToSet': {
          'comment': '$comment',
          'crop': '$crop'
        }
      },
      'comment': {
        '$addToSet': '$comment'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$action_count_temp',
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
    }
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'actions': '$action_count_temp.actions'
      },
      'comment': {
        '$first': '$comment'
      },
      'crop_count_temp': {
        '$first': '$crop_count_temp'
      },
      'actions_count_temp': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id.actions',
      'userId': {
        '$first': '$_id._id'
      },
      'comment': {
        '$first': '$comment'
      },
      'crop_count_temp': {
        '$first': '$crop_count_temp'
      },
      'actions_count_temp': {
        '$first': {
          'k': '$_id.actions',
          'v': '$actions_count_temp'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$project': {
      '_id': '$userId',
      'actions_count_temp': 1,
      'comment': 1,
      'crop_count_temp': 1
    }
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id',
      'comment': {
        '$first': '$comment'
      },
      'crop_count_temp': {
        '$first': '$crop_count_temp'
      },
      'actions_count_temp': {
        '$push': '$actions_count_temp'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$crop_count_temp',
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
    }
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'crop': '$crop_count_temp.crop'
      },
      'comment': {
        '$first': '$comment'
      },
      'actions_count_temp': {
        '$first': '$actions_count_temp'
      },
      'crop_count_temp': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id.crop',
      'userId': {
        '$first': '$_id._id'
      },
      'comment': {
        '$first': '$comment'
      },
      'actions_count_temp': {
        '$first': '$actions_count_temp'
      },
      'crop_count_temp': {
        '$first': {
          'k': '$_id.crop',
          'v': '$crop_count_temp'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$project': {
      '_id': '$userId',
      'actions_count_temp': 1,
      'comment': 1,
      'crop_count_temp': 1
    }
  },
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id',
      'comment': {
        '$first': '$comment'
      },
      'crop_count_temp': {
       ' $push': '$crop_count_temp'
      },
      'actions_count_temp': {
        '$first': '$actions_count_temp'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 1,
      'comment': 1,
      'action_count': {
        '$arrayToObject': '$actions_count_temp'
      },
      'crop_count': {
        '$arrayToObject': '$crop_count_temp'
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlaygroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q-cLbsEQH03)

I will try to shrink this, I will update it here, if it works.